# Drupal Views 3 rescan template files

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-views, drupal-7

I am having some issues with Views 3 on Drupal 7 Beta when rescanning template files. I've put a new template in my theme folder called views-view-fields--blog--block-1.tpl.php which is the filename Theme Information suggests. When I click "Rescan Template Files" the pane disappears and it doesn't bold the new template (and doesn't use it).

Anyone else seeing the same issue or is it just me? Just to clarify, I'm using Drupal 7 Beta but I've also set it up in Drupal 6 in the same way and it rescans fine...

Just want to know if this is an issue with D7 or something wrong with the way I've set it up.

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the template file IS being used, but views isn't bolding it. I have put it in the Views bug queue. Resolved (sort of)

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely mission critical that you use Drupal 7? As you have mentioned yourself that the same thing works in Drupal 6. I would suggest that you post this question in the Views 3 issue queue http://drupal.org/project/issues/views?categories=All